# Redirect to the same page but with a message in it

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I'm making a login page in JSP. I have an `index.jsp` page where the form exists and some javascript scriplets. Connectivity to oracle database and checking for username and password in database is done in `check1.jsp` file

My issue is that after entering username and password, when I press login button, I have linked the form to `check1.jsp`, if username and password matches and exist, it redirects to `welcome.jsp` , but if username doesnot exist or password is not matched I have to get back to `index.jsp` **showing a small message below box that username doesn't exist OR Password is not matched**, currently I am just redirecting to `index.jsp`.

How should I show that appropriate small message below login box on that same `index.jsp` page??

Comment: you can just add a query string to your url when redirecting to index.jsp from check1.jsp, like attempts counter or anything else which shows login attempt failed and check for it in index.jsp, if it is there, then show the message ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REDIRECT TO `index.jsp?message=<your custom msg>`

And then you can check if message parameter is set and get them via GET parameter

***EDIT: (after comments)***

I am not a java programmer but googling gives me this,

```
if(request.getParameter("message") == null) {
     // User has opened index.jsp for first time (no redirection)
}
else{
    // user has been redirected from check1.jsp
    string message = request.getParameter("message");
    // Do anything with message

}
```

Comment: Thanks, how to check the parameter is set or not? either in javascript/ajax or jsp?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a flag that is triggered in `check1.jsp` and sent back to `index.jsp`.

and in `index.php` , you could put  a check for the flag to display error if it's turned ON.